# SnapSVG Load vs img.src

Tags: javascript, svg

I've been able to load other SVG's into Snap but there's a one that won't show up no matter what I do or how I look at it. It works fine outside of Snap by src:ing it inside an  tag.

The culprit is http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Icehockeylayout.svg

I've tried moving it around to see if it was placed off view somehow and looked at the plain SVG source to find any answers to no avail.

Hovering over the loaded svg tag (not the Snap svg tag) inside the DOM Tree in devtools shows nothing - as if it was hidden (no bounding box highlighting thing).

Am I missing something obvious? The svg doesn't seem special compared to others. Is the issue with Snap or SVG?

Try this jsFiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/rdtztLe8/

```
var s = Snap(400,300);

var url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Icehockeylayout.svg";

var d = document.getElementById('text');

Snap.load(url, function(f) {
    s.append(f);
    d.innerHTML = 'svg "loaded" with snap';

    setTimeout(function(){
        d.innerHTML = "let's try with img tag";
    }, 2000);

    // try with ing tag
    setTimeout(function() {
        var i = document.getElementById('img');
        i.src = url;
        d.innerHTML = "img tag works - but not snap sag?";
    }, 5000);    
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So this question was answered/figured out by Mardeg in #svg of mozilla IRC (sand.mozilla.org).

Basically snap failed to deal with the xml svg prefixing of the tags. A quick %s/svg://g later it was working perfectly.

```
<Mardeg> jinjin: is the Snap library failing because http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Icehockeylayout.svg prefixes every tag with the svg namespace, like <svg:svg> and <svg:pattern> etc?
<jinjin> hmm
<jinjin> you might be onto something the other sag's I tried don't seem to do that
<jinjin> will test
<Mardeg> xml namespacing is something that is allowed in standalone .svg files, being xml compatible. But I'm not sure how that then behaves as straight code inside .html files.. unless Snap is failing to include the namespacing when injecting the code into the page or something
<Mardeg> usually the declaration is xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" for svg files, but xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" is also valid
<Mardeg> which means everything is prefixed with svg:
<jinjin> mother god you are right!
```